# Spring + Angular set up and security

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, maven, spring-security

I am wondering what the best way is to setup a project that contains a Spring RESTful API along with the ability to serve up static Angularjs pages to consume the RESTful web service. The below implementation works but I am now looking to add security into the application and I am unsure how to apply Spring Security to both the REST Api and the static pages.

- Is the below setup correct for my end goal?
- How do I secure both the REST Api && the static pages?

I have the following project structure

[image: Project Structure]

Servlet Config

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;  
import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;  

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;  
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;  
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet; 



@ComponentScan
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {  

        servletContext.addFilter("corsFilter", new CORSFilter());

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();  
        ctx.register(WebMvcConfig.class);  
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);                 

        Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));  
        dynamic.addMapping("/api/*");  
        dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);  
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would follow the series of articles on spring.io blog that explains exactly what you are looking for: Spring + Security + Angular JS.

Here the articles:

http://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/spring-and-angular-js-a-secure-single-page-application
https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii
http://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/the-resource-server-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-iii
http://spring.io/blog/2015/01/28/the-api-gateway-pattern-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-iv
http://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v